# AdMob - getting iOS App approved (app-ads.txt not crawled)

Tags: admob, adsense

I have been trying for quite some time to set up my iOS App for serving ads with AdMob, but without success.

The problem lies in the fact that whenever I apply to the AdMob program, I my application gets rejected due to not being conformant to the AdMob policy. Actually, the very same problem happens to my applications to the AdSense program.

I believe that I have addressed every point in the AdMob policy, but for some reason the `app-ads.txt` file hasn't been picked up by Google's crawler yet. More details:

- It is located at the root of my domain like so `https://myapp.com/app-ads.txt`.
- I've double checked that the contents of the file is exactly what I am being told on AdMob's website it should be, i.e. `google.com, pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, DIRECT, <hash>`
- I have already tried out test ads on an iOS device and everything works, except for my account not being approved.

I am not able to contact any human being from Google to ask for support. My main suspicion is that it is because of the `app-ads.txt`, which hasn't been crawled.

- I have an **empty** `robots.txt` file at the root of my domain `https://myapp.com/robots.txt` and the correct `ads-app.txt` file `https://myapp.com/app-ads.txt` (also `ads.txt` file at `https://myapp.com/ads.txt` for AdSense [in case they are related])

My developer's website on App Store is set to `https://myapp.com`.

ANY kind of help or direction, would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: `app-ads.txt` can affect revenue but might not be the cause of rejection. Could you provide the reason stated for rejection? Is the app live on Google Play?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the exact reason. I just receive a generic message saying that I don't comply with their policies: 

"Thank you for your interest in AdMob. After reviewing your application, our specialists have found that it does not meet our program criteria. Therefore, we are unable to accept you into our program."

The app is live on Apple Store and I was able to select it in AdMob's interface.

Comment: @koleS I deleted my answer and I'm sorry I couldn't help. I hope your problem gets solved soon. Good luck my friend!